# How to create an initializer for a UINavigationController derived object?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, subclassing

I've got a class that inherits from `UINavigationController` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

I'm setting the delegate in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.navigationController?.delegate = self
```

However the delegate methods (such as `willShow`, `didShow`) are not getting called as things are pushed to the stack.

Thus after reading past questions, I'm trying to set the delegate earlier than in `viewDidLoad` in an initializer. I've tried a million combinations, but they either don't compile or don't get called.

Won't compile:

```
convenience init()
{
    super.init()
    self.navigationController?.delegate = self
}
```

Won't compile:

```
convenience init()
{
    init(rootViewController: self)
    self.navigationController?.delegate = self
}
```

Won't get called

```
convenience init()
{
    self.init()
    self.navigationController?.delegate = self
}
```

And so on and so on, trying things based on what the compiler says is the problem. But the compiler says things like "add `self` to call," so you add it then it says "remove `self` from call" and so on and so on. I've tried millions of combinations, tried searching past questions and copy/paste their initializers. I still can't get anything working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `self.delegate = self`, not `self.navigationController?.delegate = self` since `self` is a `UINavigationController`.

You are trying to set the delegate of the navigation controller's navigation controller. But you aren't (and can't) putting the navigation controller inside another navigation controller.